# Unity. Fixed Update isn't sensing my jump input well. Normal update launches my character to random heights when space is pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know what's up. I usually do my jumping on the update function. This is my first big game though other than other prototypes or bad game attempts I've done.

This is my jump code

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isDead == false)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (OnGround == true)
            {
                rb.velocity=  new Vector2 (rb.velocity.x, jumpforce * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I sometimes miss a few jumps on fixed update. But when I put it in my update function it jumps so low sometimes, like two or three times and then it launches me so high. It's just so random and weird. Is there anything I can do about this or will I just have to deal with fixedupdate? I even tried lateupdate if that matters.

Comment: Hey John! I noticed you are a little new to StackOverflow and I just wanted to explain how the forum works a bit. I noticed you have [asked quite a few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15858343/john), which is fine as that is what StackOverflow is for, but you have never accepted answers to any of your questions. If you feel any of your questions were solved by another user's post, you can close the question by clicking on the green checkmark to the left of that post. It lets anyone else that stumbles upon your question in the future know that it has an answer and was solved.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry for not doing that, that would probably be very helpful for others.

Comment: No worries just wanted to let you know as you were newer to the platform. Not everyone knows how it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is to place all keyboard/mouse input into the `Update` method and not the `FixedUpdate` method. The reason for this is because `FixedUpdate` is not a frame by frame process, but is called at fixed time increments which can be more or less calls in a certain frame period.

Input data is determined every frame, so in `FixedUpdate` where it can run in-between frames, skip frames, etc. you have the possibility of losing input. Instead, move your input code to the `Update` method which is called every frame. You will no longer lose input.

The issue with setting your physics calls in `Update` is because all physics code should be placed in `FixedUpdate`. As `Update` can run faster or slower than the physics system in your game, placing physics-based calls in it can have unexpected results.

Unity:

> FixedUpdate should be used instead of Update when dealing with Rigidbody. For example when adding a force to a rigidbody, you have to apply the force every fixed frame inside FixedUpdate instead of every frame inside Update. [Tell me more...](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html#:%7E:text=FixedUpdate%20should%20be%20used%20instead,of%20every%20frame%20inside%20Update.)

The solution is to cache your input from `Update` and then set using the resulting input from this method in `FixedUpdate` to determine your physics.

```
private bool justJumped = false;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(justJumped)
    {
        justJumped = false;
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (!justJumped && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && OnGround && !isDead)
    {
        justJumped = true;
    }
}
```

I would also recommend not setting velocity directly as if any other outside forces are acting on your player, they will be disregarded. Instead, use [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html). I swapped your direct velocity set with an `AddForce`. I would also not multiply by `Time.deltaTime`. That value is just a float value for how much time has passed since the last frame. It should be used when doing movement in small increments such as with a `Lerp`. If you want to set velocity directly, remove the `Time.deltaTime` product and decrease your `jumpforce` by a lot. You will find the outcome to be the same.

Comment: Nice answer.  I hope you don't mind but I added a quote from Unity re `FixedUpdate`.  +1

Comment: @MickyD Don't mind at all. Definitely brings some authority and further clarity to the answer.

Comment: @TEEBQNE I am not very expert in Unity. I have just started learning it now. Your solution works fine and propably it is the correct way in order to do things like this. Anyway, I also tried to lower the Fixed Timestep setting (in Project settings -> Time) to a very low value. In my case 0.002 (instead the default 0.02) and it worked fine as well. But I don't know if lowering so much this value can cause slowings or other issues when the physics becomes more complex than that simple of my beginner 2d single player one.

Comment: @FedericoTomasi Sorry for the late reply don't use SO much anymore. For a physics light game shouldn't worry but can cause unexpected results. 0.2 or 50 calls per frame is the default. Changing this number just changes the amount of times physics is attempted to be updated outside of the normal game loop. For your use case it shouldn't cause issues.