# Is it ok to read inputs like this in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Suddenly I got the idea that GetKeyDown input can also be read in fixedupdate, especially since I already use the jumpContinuing variable.
This way you can avoid Update (if you need to). But there must be a catch.
I'm not saying it's better, I'm just wondering if it's normal to do it this way.

Here is the code in FixedUpdate

```
        if (!jumpContinuing && grounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            jumpContinuing = true;
        }
        if (jumpContinuing)
        {
            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                jumpContinuing = false;
            }
        }
```

And in Update

```
        if (grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            jumpContinuing = true;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            jumpContinuing = false;
        }
```

Comment: The short answer is "No, it is not ok". However, why are you even trying to do this?

Comment: "Suddenly I got the idea" is the perfect beginning to most code tragedies.

Comment: @Morion Just experimenting. Why it is not ok by the way?

Comment: First of all, it is recommended to use it in the Update in the documentation. Secondly, fixed updates are not called more often. They are simply called several times in case of Update took longer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity. Fixed Update isn't sensing my jump input well. Normal update launches my character to random heights when space is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612051/unity-fixed-update-isnt-sensing-my-jump-input-well-normal-update-launches-my)

Comment: @MaxPlay this applies to single event input (`GetKeyDown`/`GetKeyUp`) and is mitigated by OP using continuous input (`GetKey`)

Comment: it certainly works, but what you wanna look is Unity New Input System, you map your keys in actions and you bind your function with the action context

Answer (score -1):

Well you can actually do that if you like but this can sometime cause Input skips as fixed update are mainly used for physics related stuff while update method is called in every frame so using fixed update for checking Input will definately cause Input skips in a advance level game.

Comment: This is wrong. Reading input in `FixedUpdate` can result in skipping inputs not delaying them. You can press and release a key between two `FixedUpdate` calls and then your `IsKeyDown` will not be true. [Longer explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67612132/5593150).

Comment: I this case i'm using GetKey in FixedUpdate, so it checks not a single frame and it works just fine, that's the point